# Android ListView clear

Tags: android, listview, adapter, getter-setter

I have a ListView. I want to dynamically change the contents of the ListView. I used adapter to pass the values to it. when I pass the values it accepts and displays but when I press back button and pass new data it still displays old data and along with new data.

I have tried

> arraylist.clear() ,
>    adapter_object.notifyDataSetChanged(); ,
>   listview.setAdapter(null);

but none of those worked.

Here's how I pass values to getter and setter class

```
  for (int i = 0; i <FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.size(); i++) {
            flight_one_way_detail.add(new Flight_info_details(FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString(), FlightTboSearch.flight_departure_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_arrival_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString()));

            flight_one_way_adapter = new Flight_info_adapter(View_fligh_info.this, flight_one_way_detail);

        }
```

Here's the adapter code

```
public class Flight_info_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;


public static ArrayList<Flight_info_details> rowItems;

Flight_info_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Flight_info_details> rowItems) {

    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView flight;
    TextView departur;
    TextView arrival;
    ImageView img_logo;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.flight_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.flight = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flight);
    holder.departur = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.departure);
    holder.arrival = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrival);
    holder.img_logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
    try
    {
        final Flight_info_details row_pos = rowItems.get(position);
        String flight = String.valueOf(row_pos.getflight());
        String departur=String.valueOf(row_pos.getdeparture());
        String arrival=String.valueOf(row_pos.getarrival());
        String flight_name=String.valueOf(row_pos.getflight_name());

        if(flight_name.equals("SpiceJet"))
        {

            holder.img_logo.setImageBitmap(View_fligh_info.spicejet);
        }else if(flight_name.equals("Indigo"))
        {
            holder.img_logo.setImageBitmap(View_fligh_info.indigo);
        }else if(flight_name.equals("Jet Airways"))
        {
            Log.e("confirmation_Adapter-",flight_name);
            holder.img_logo.setImageBitmap(View_fligh_info.jetairways);
        }else if(flight_name.equals("Air India"))
        {
            holder.img_logo.setImageBitmap(View_fligh_info.ai);
        }else if(flight_name.equals("Klm Uk"))
        {
            holder.img_logo.setImageBitmap(View_fligh_info.uk);
        }else if(flight_name.equals("Air Asia"))
        {
            holder.img_logo.setImageBitmap(View_fligh_info.airasia);
        }
        holder.flight.setText(flight);
        holder.departur.setText(departur);
        holder.arrival.setText(arrival);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("PASS_ADAP ERROR:", e.getMessage());
    }
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Here's the getter setter class

```
public class Flight_info_details {

String flight;
String departure;
String arrival;
String flight_name;





public String getflight(){return flight;}
public void setflight() {
    this.flight = flight;
}

public String getdeparture() {return departure;}
public void setdeparture() {this.departure = departure;}

public String getarrival() {return arrival;}
public void setarrival() {this.arrival = arrival;}

public String getflight_name() {return flight_name;}
public void setflight_name() {this.flight_name = flight_name;}

public Flight_info_details(String flight, String departure, String arrival, String flight_name)
{

    this.flight = flight;
    this.departure=departure;
    this.arrival=arrival;
    this.flight_name=flight_name;


}
}
```

where am I going wrong

EDIT-1
ACTIVITY to set values

```
public class View_fligh_info extends AppCompatActivity{

ArrayList<ViewFlightDetails> newUsers;

public static Bitmap spicejet,indigo,ai,uk,SaudiArabianAirlines,EthiopianAirlinesSC,KenyaAirways,ThaiAirwaysInternational,jetairways,airasia,HahnAirSystems,TurkishAirlines,AirMauritius,EmiratesAirlines,OmanAviation,SriLankanAirlines,Alitalia,EtihadAirways,AirFacilities,GulfAir;

TextView return_text;
Button next;
LinearLayout retur_text_2;
ListView flight_information,return_list;

public static ArrayList<Flight_info_details> flight_one_way_detail;
public static Flight_info_adapter flight_one_way_adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    setContentView(R.layout.view_flight_info);
    return_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.return_text);


    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);

    flight_information = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_oneway);

    spicejet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.spice);
    indigo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.indigo);
    ai = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ai);
    uk = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.uk);
    jetairways = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.jet);
    airasia = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.airasia);

    HahnAirSystems = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.h1);
    Alitalia = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.az);
    EtihadAirways = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ey);
    AirFacilities = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.fz);
    GulfAir = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.gf);
    SriLankanAirlines = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ul);
    OmanAviation = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.wy);
    EmiratesAirlines = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ek);
    AirMauritius = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.mk);
    TurkishAirlines = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.tk);
    EthiopianAirlinesSC = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.et);
    KenyaAirways = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.kq);
    ThaiAirwaysInternational = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.tg);
    SaudiArabianAirlines = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.sv);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(View_fligh_info.this,"HELLO WORLD",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


    if (FlightHome.oneway.isChecked())
    {


        Toast.makeText(View_fligh_info.this,"Oneway Trip",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        retur_text_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


       //flight_information.setAdapter(null);
        flight_one_way_detail =new ArrayList<Flight_info_details>();
        flight_one_way_detail.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i <FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.size(); i++) {

            flight_one_way_detail.add(new Flight_info_details(FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString(), FlightTboSearch.flight_departure_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_arrival_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString()));

            flight_one_way_adapter = new Flight_info_adapter(View_fligh_info.this, flight_one_way_detail);

        }

        flight_one_way_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        flight_information.setAdapter(flight_one_way_adapter);


  //flight_one_way_detail.getAdapter().notify();


        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(flight_information.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        for (int i = 0; i < flight_one_way_adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = flight_one_way_adapter.getView(i, null, flight_information);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = flight_information.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (flight_information.getDividerHeight() * (flight_one_way_adapter.getCount() - 1));
        flight_information.setLayoutParams(params);
        flight_information.requestLayout();



    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    flight_one_way_detail.clear();
 //     flight_information.setAdapter(null);

    Intent i=new Intent(View_fligh_info.this,FlightTboSearch.class);
    startActivity(i);


}


}
```

Comment: Please post your activity code also.

Comment: which activity xml file?@SanjayKakadiya

Comment: Not xml. Post java code from where you set the adapter.

Comment: @Newlearner I don't know your logic but why r u initialising adapter in for loop?

Comment: to check for more possibilities,or values my be multiple so i added in for loop.@Raghavendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't what exactly your logic is to setting adapter . But you should never create adapter inside loop so correct the things below .

```
for (int i = 0; i <FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.size(); i++) {
        flight_one_way_detail.add(new Flight_info_details(FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString(), FlightTboSearch.flight_departure_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_arrival_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString()));
    }
    flight_one_way_adapter = new Flight_info_adapter(View_fligh_info.this, flight_one_way_detail);
    flight_information.setAdapter(flight_one_way_adapter);
```

Second thing is `onbackPressed()`. As i am seeing you did not finish the current activity on back button click why is that ? I think you should finish your activity and there is is no need to reseting adapter in this case .
Or if you want to keep it that way.Then just clearing the list will reset the adapter .

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

if(flight_one_way_adapter!=null){
flight_one_way_detail.clear();
flight_one_way_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
Intent i=new Intent(View_fligh_info.this,FlightTboSearch.class);
startActivity(i);
 }
```

Comment: There should be no need to override `onBackPressed()` at all.

Comment: Yeah thats what i said . in first case . I do not know what exactly the questioner wants to achieve.

Comment: Thx . Be aware of Activity stack cause if do not finish() activity on onBackpress() then it will popUp from stack when back from your FlightTboSearch Activity .

Answer (score 1):

```
public ArrayList<Flight_info_details> flight_one_way_detail;
```

flight_one_way_detail is static which should not be.

As static concept, only one object of flight_one_way_detail is init for your activity so even after coming back from other activity you will still get that object and you are adding new flight detail in it so it show old one as well as new one

addition @Raghavendra suggest creating new adapter should not be in loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should only call `new Flight_info_adapter()` one time. I suggest creating the `ArrayList` first then passing it to the `Flight_info_adapter()` constructor:

```
ArrayList<Flight_info_detail> flight_one_way_detail = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.size(); i++) {
    flight_one_way_detail.add(new Flight_info_details(FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString(), FlightTboSearch.flight_departure_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_arrival_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString()));
}

flight_one_way_adapter = new Flight_info_adapter(View_fligh_info.this, flight_one_way_detail);
```

There is no need to call `clear()` immediately after creating a list. The new list is guaranteed to be empty.

Note that the values in the adapter are only stored in memory. If the user quits your app, all data will be lost. In order to keep data more permanently, I suggest that you create a SQLite database and use a CursorAdapter. There are several good online tutorials and blogs that illustrate how to do this.

Comment: i have already called flight_one_way_detail.clear() before setting to constructor and i  did  create ArrayList once but it still shows last data.

Answer (score 0):

first, in your adapter your arraylist should not be static.

second, make private method to your activity. like this-

```
private ArrayList<modelclass> getdata(){

        ArrayList<modelclass> flight_one_way_detail = new ArrayList<>() ;
        flight_one_way_detail.clear();
        flight_one_way_detail.add(new Flight_info_details(FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString(), FlightTboSearch.flight_departure_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_arrival_jeet.get(i), FlightTboSearch.flight_name_jeet.get(i).toString()));
        return list ;
    }
```

and then pass the arraylist to your adapter from onCreate method.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
        listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, getdata()) ;
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    }
```

i hope with this two steps you will get your desire result. if it not happen then clear your arraylist from the constructor of your adapter. like this-

```
public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<modelclass> list){
        this.list.clear();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.list=list;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

but, its not a good practice. because, everytime you are passing to brand new arraylist to your adapter. if and only if you don't get the desire result then you can clear the list from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should not start new activiy in onBackPressed() function. Its basic function is to return to previous activity. And after this function, onResume() function of previous activity runs and there, you should update your list and adapter.